# How can I judge the performance of different models of time series?

Tags: r

I am new in time series. Currently I am using the ARIMA model and the ETS model to analyze a time series.

My question is that how I can determine the performance of different types of models. Can I simply use AIC or BIC on different models?

Moreover, if I perform log or box-cox transformation on the time series, can I still compare AIC or BIC to judge the performance of the models? I mean, different transformations can lead to different AIC or BIC of a same model.

Thank you.

Comment: This is not really a programming question and better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I vote to close & migrate.

Comment: A standard accuracy measure such as RMSE.